# Will absolute positioned element affect the below relative positioned element. How to fix?

Tags: css

Page has rows which is positioned relative. Each row has col1 and col2 which are floated left and right. Problem is in the last row col1 and col2. they are not floating as intended. whats causing that? In fiddle it seem to work right. but not in my page. I've a absolute positioned element above that row. will that affect these elements?

Comment: So what do you want to do? You say it doesn't work but you don't describe your intended outcome.

Comment: @Drackir --it should do as the floats. col1 float:left, col2 float: right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `.col2-content` float left as well and it will work.

Comment: I have no idea what you changed on your site now, but before I could fix it simply by making that class float left.

Comment: i floated col2 for this row alone by adding id to it.           <div class="row last"><div class="col1-content" id="news"><div class="para">    </div></div>                                                     <div class="col2-content" id="info"><div class="para"></div></div><!-- end col2-content--></div><!-- end row-->                                                      Now it fixed it.